# Where does Sitecore convert item paths to domain names?

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore6

I'm running a multi-site Sitecore 6.5 installation, upgrading to Sitecore 6.6. In 6.5, links to the top level domains behave normally, i.e. a link to the /sitecore/content/mydomain/home item resolves to mydomain.mysite.org, because it's set up to do so in web.config via the `<sites>` entries.

After the upgrade to 6.6, that's not happening. The `<sites>` entries are still in place, but the URL just points to mysite.org/sitecore/content/mydomain.home. Sitecore has been unable to pinpoint the issue because we have a number of customizations to the base setup (done by the initial vendor that set up the site). I'm assuming one of these customizations is to blame, but I'm having trouble pinpointing exactly where in the pipeline this is breaking down.

The actual code that's rendering the links is calling Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(), which is returning the bad URL immediately after the 6.6. upgrade package is installed. Any idea where the actual domain conversion is taking place, so I can start backing out some customizations to at least know where the problem is?

**Update:**

Here is the `<sites>` section of the web.config (via showconfig.aspx). This is after applying suggestions from the answers to date, i.e. adding targetHostName and making the main site last in the order of site entries.

```
    <sites>
        <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" />
        <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />
        <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
        <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
        <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
        <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />

        <site name="ga_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="medicare.martinspoint.local" targetHostName="medicare.martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/GA" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" loginPage="http://martinspoint.local/account/login" />
        <site name="groupplan_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="groupplan.martinspoint.local" targetHostName="groupplan.martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/GroupPlan" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
        <site name="hcc_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="healthcarecenters.martinspoint.local" targetHostName="healthcarecenters.martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/HCC" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
        <site name="usfhp_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="tricare.martinspoint.local" targetHostName="tricare.martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/usfhp" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" loginPage="http://martinspoint.local/account/login" />
        <site name="my_martinspoint_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="connect.martinspoint.local" targetHostName="connect.martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mymartinspoint" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
        <site name="martinspoint_website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" hostName="martinspoint.local" targetHostName="martinspoint.local" rootPath="/sitecore/content/martinspoint" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />

        <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="HQ" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
        <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
        <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
        <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
    </sites>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl` is determined by the `LinkProvider` which is configured in your config, here:

```
  <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
           addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" 
           languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" 
           lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    </providers>
  </linkManager>
```

You vendor has probably overridden that setting with a custom provider.

Comment: They had indeed overridden this setting, but I updated it back to the Sitecore standard (as you show here) and it's still not resolving the URL correctly.

Comment: Try to set the targetHostName attributes on your <site> nodes if yo u haven't done so already. If you can share your entire <sites> configuration, I can take a look and see if anything else may help.

Comment: Maybe they customized the SiteResolver? Take a look at the <httpRequestBegin> pipeline configuration and see if the SiteResolver processor is overridden

Comment: @RuudvanFalier I added targetHostNames and updated the question with the resulting sites section. No luck so far. Thanks for the suggestions. Let me know if anything else jumps out at you.

Comment: @ElenaZlateva I checked the pipeline and it's using the standard Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver. Good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as through you are trying to link from one domain to another (or a subdomain at least). Make sure `Rendering.SiteResolving=true`, which is the default value but it is worth checking:

```
<!--  SITE RESOLVING
  While rendering item links, some items may belong to different site. Setting this to true
  make LinkManager try to resolve target site in order to use the right host name.
  Default value: true
-->
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolving" value="true" />
```

As Ruud has suggested, sharing the `<sites>` of your configuration may help and check the `targetHostName`. It's not [listed as a value](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/targetHostName.aspx) in 6.6 config but you need to set this if you have [multiple hostNames set](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/dont-use-hostname.html).

Also verify the ordering of your `<site>` config elements this that determines which site context is matched. More specific domains should be ordered first, so `mydomain.mysite.org` should be listed before `mysite.org`.

Check your final configuration from `http://<url>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` (or use Sitecore Rocks) since it may be patched in using a Sitecore Include file.

**EDIT:** I've remembered what the issue is :)

Unfortunately the default UrlOptions and LinkManager ignore the `Rendering.SiteResolving` (or maybe it was a bug in this particular version of Sitecore), since the default LinkProvider does not initialize this setting!

You need to create your own LinkProvider, inheriting from the Sitecore one and overwrite the `GetItemUrl()` method passing through this setting:

```
namespace Sitecore.Sample
{
    public class CustomLinkProvider : LinkProvider
    {
        public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
        {
            // use the SiteResolving option set in config
            if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
                options.SiteResolving = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving;

            return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your config switch out with your provider:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="customProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" ... />
    <add name="customProvider" type="Sitecore.Sample.CustomLinkProvider, Sitecore.Sample"
         addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" 
         languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" 
         lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

You can read more about it in this [blog post](http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/using-cross-site-links-dynamic-links/).

Comment: Rendering.SiteResolving was already set to "true". I added the targetHostName, even though the link suggests that the way our sites are configured it's not necessary. I also made sure the main site was listed last. Still no luck. I've updated the question with the resulting sites section. Thanks for the suggestions so far. Let me know if you see anything else.

Comment: You are right, `targetHostName` makes no difference when you only have a single `hostName` set. Are the bad URLs only when you try to link to items across sites, or also also within the same site?

Comment: Across sites. When I'm on the main site, all main site links work fine. If I manually go to one of the sub-sites, all sub-site links work fine, but links to other sites are broken - they all take the form of mydomain.mysite.org/sitecore/content/otherdomain/home.

Comment: I think I've remembered what the issue was! See my updated answer

Comment: Still no luck. To be safe, I created a new UrlOptions object with all the settings manually set as they should be, including SiteResolving set to true, and GetItemUrl() is still returning "/sitecore/content/mysite/home" for all but the current site, which returns "/".

Comment: And did you change the `defaultProvider` setting to point to your new LinkProvider? Not sure what it is then... Assume if you set a breakpoint it is hitting your code? Or maybe add some logging to see what it is doing...

Comment: Yep, the defaultProvider for the linkManager is pointing to the Sitecore standard link provider. I did set a breakpoint and watched it hit the code and return the bad URL.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Did you create a LinkProvider (with the above code), add an entry to `LinkManager` (like in Ruud's answer) and change the defaultProvider attribute to your new one? Alternatively from code call `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions)` where SiteResolving is true on your options and see what you get for that specific call in code.

Comment: The second option: I manually set SiteResolving to true, but it didn't help. Interestingly, after reading the blog post you posted, I found the "part 2" post for that topic, and the code posted there is returning the correct URL. That seemed to be for a Sitecore 6.4.1 bug, but for whatever reason it seems to be fixing my 6.6 issue. Here's the URL: http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/using-cross-site-links-aka-dynamic-links-part-2/

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I would raise a ticket with Sitecore Support if you have access, I can't say I've had this issue (and I worked on a 6.6 install recently.